# How to remove title bar in awesome window manager ver >4

Tags: window-managers, awesome-wm

I've recently upgraded my machine, and am now at awesome version 4.x.  There is now a titlebar of sorts with close, ontop, floating, maximized, etc... buttons on right.  Can I get rid of this?  What config would I use to have this be universally turned off?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your rc.lua file, look for

```
-- Add title bars to normal clients and dialogs
{ rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }
  }, properties = { titlebars_enabled = true }
},
```

and change

`titlebars_enabled = true`

to

`titlebars_enabled = false`

Answer (score 3):

A bit late for this (1 year ago !)...
I replace as said previously by Emmanuel in the rules section. But when I made titlebars appear they were empty, no icons, no textbox... nothing.
My workaround was to leave `titlebars_enabled = true` in the rules section.
and in the signals section (in the `"manage"` handle) : add the titlebar and hide it (the 2 last lines in the code below) when I start awesome. When I toggle its display, the titlebar appears with icons and texts :

```
-- Signal function to execute when a new client appears.
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)
  -- Set the windows at the slave,
  -- i.e. put it at the end of others instead of setting it master.
  -- if not awesome.startup then awful.client.setslave(c) end

 if awesome.startup and
  not c.size_hints.user_position
  and not c.size_hints.program_position then
    -- Prevent clients from being unreachable after screen count changes.
    awful.placement.no_offscreen(c)
 end
--
 awful.titlebar(c,{size=10})
 awful.titlebar.hide(c)
end)
```

Comment: well, `awful.titlebar(c,{size=10})` not a must for this function just changing the size of title bar. and to re-show the title bar, `awful.titlebar.toggle(c)` will do.

Answer (score 3):

Just to combine both answers from @Emmanuel and @david and have a full example with hidden titlebar by default and a key combination to toggle it:

Leave `titlebars_enabled = true` in the `rule_any` block, this avoids the problem of having an empty titlebar when showing it.

Hide the titlebar when a new client(window) appears adding `awful.titlebar.hide(c)` in the `manage` signal:

```
client.connect_signal("manage", function (c)
    -- ... more code

    awful.titlebar.hide(c)
end)
```

Then add a key binding, in this case `Modkey` + `Control` + `t`, to call `awful.titlebar.toggle`.

```
clientkeys = my_table.join(
    -- ... more key bindings
    -- Remember to add a comma to the end of the previous keybinding above!

    awful.key({ modkey, 'Control' }, 't', function (c) awful.titlebar.toggle(c) end,
        {description = 'toggle title bar', group = 'client'})
)
```